# Querying a table containing CLOB value from oracle database using Criteria

Tags: oracle, hibernate, clob

I am trying to access a table containing three columns id(Long),name,value(CLOB)

I am using the Criteria in hibernate to get all the rows in the table.

The code is as follows :

```
List<Configuration> configurationList = new ArrayList<Configuration>();
    try {
        Session localSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
       Criteria criteria= localSession.createCriteria("com.bean.Configuration");
       configurationList = criteria.list();

    } finally {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
    return configurationList;
```

The problem is when the list is returned it contains no data. I am sure that the table contains rows.It doesnot show any exceptions or errors.Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Have you tried: localSession.createCriteria(Configuration.class); ?

Comment: Another issue with this is i'm not getting any errors